# Assigning domain name to Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I'm attempting to assign a domain name to my Google Cloud VM external IP. I was following some walkthroughs and getting a bit confused. I set up apache with a simple "Hello" message when you visit my external IP. The walkthroughs I'm following are providing steps to reserve a new static external IP and creating a DNS zone.

Could someone provide clarification on why I would need to secure a new static external IP address when it appears I already have one assigned?

Comment: The public IP that your VM already has is an ephimeral one which means that if the VM is stopped or restarted, there is a possibility this public IP changes. The problem will be that if it changes, your DNS will continue pointing to the old one which means your site will be not accesible until you update the DNS with the new IP. Reserving the public IP will warranty your VM always has the same IP https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: Makes sense. In the docs it states "Compute Engineer free tier does not charge for an external IP address." Would that be refering to the an ephemeral or assigned exrnal?

Comment: A good question, it should be more explicit in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#compute) but I assume (!) it's an ephemeral IP. I submitted doc feedback for this.

Comment: You're right. Thank you

Comment: @bighelpdiscord does Ferrigina Pelona and DazWilkin answers all of your question?

Comment: Yes they did. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As discussed by @Ferregina Pelona in the comment section. The public IP that your VM already has is an ephimeral one which means that if the VM is stopped or restarted, there is a possibility this public IP changes. The problem will be that if it changes, your DNS will continue pointing to the old one which means your site will be not accesible until you update the DNS with the new IP. [Reserving the public IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) will warranty your VM always has the same IP.

Also, added by @DazWilkin. it should be more explicit in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#compute) but I assume (!) it's an ephemeral IP. I submitted doc feedback for this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're following a guide like [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial)

The tutorial demonstrates the following steps when assigning a domain to a VM which would act as a server:

-Register a domain name using Google Domains or Cloud Domains

-Create a virtual machine (VM) instance

-Run a basic Apache web server

-Set up your domain using Cloud DNS

-Update name servers

-Verify your setup

However, there is a very important note that I believe clarifies completely the scenario you faced and the questions regarding this which states:

**Note:**`By default, the VM instance that you create receives an ephemeral external IP address. Ephemeral external IP addresses are lost whenever the VM instance shuts down or reboots for any reason (for example, maintenance). To avoid shutdowns and reboots, use a static external IP address for web hosting. For instructions about how to reserve a static external IP address, see Reserving a static external IP address.`

My suggestion would be that you try always to find an official docummentation according to the configuration/products you're expecting to use so as shown in this section, these are the advices that could avoid you yo fall into errors while moving forward. I hops this info make sense for you...

Cheers,